# Как убрать выделение элемента в ContextMenu C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как убрать выделение элемента в ContextMenu, если он не является элементом MenuItem.

Полное выделение ContextMenu мешает скрин ниже(красные стрелки)?
[image]

Хочу оставить только выделение элементов(Зеленая стрелка)

Вот код xaml

```
 <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu >
     <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <MenuItem Header="Причины:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <Separator Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6"/>

        <MenuItem x:Name="Edit" Header="Изменить" Click="Edit_Click" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="Delete" Header="Удалить" Click="Delete_Click" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8"/>

        <MenuItem Header="Количество:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="false"/>
        <MenuItem Header="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <MenuItem Header="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <MenuItem Header="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"/>
        <MenuItem Header="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"/>
        <MenuItem Header="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6"/>
        <MenuItem Header="7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7"/>
        <MenuItem Header="8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8"/>
        <MenuItem Header="9" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9"/>
        <MenuItem Header="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10"/>

        <MenuItem Header="По болезни" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="По заявлению" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Прочие" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Служебная записка" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Неуважительная причина" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"/>
     </Grid>
  </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Вы проосто используете меню не по назначению, отсюда и проблемы. Я думаю, вам нужно использовать `ControlTemplate` в стиле, а не вносить `Grid` в контент, так как из контента генерится автоматом `MenuItem`, который вам и мешает.

Comment: А зачем у вас там Grid? Ваше контекстное меню, получается, состоит из одного элемента, которым является Grid, поэтому и выделяется целиком